# OnClickListener code runs but breakpoint not hit (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, onclick

In my project, setting a breakpoint anywhere except View.OnClickListener definitions causes the app to break. I can confirm that the listener properly runs with a log statement.

Even placing a breakpoint inside functions called by the OnClickListener causes a break, but putting any breakpoint inside the listener function does not break.

```
private final View.OnClickListener listener = (v) -> {
   int foo = 5; // breakpoint here, doesn't break.
   function1(); // breakpoint here, doesn't break.
    .....
}

void function1() { 
   int bar = 5; // breakpoint here, breaks.
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by app breaks? Do you mean app crashes? If yes then post the error stacktrace. If not then what is your actual requirement?

Comment: @NadeemShaikh By break I mean that when debugging, the execution properly stops at a breakpoint. So in this case the breakpoints inside the listener aren't doing anything, while the breakpoints in function1() are properly causing the debugging to stop so I can step over code.

Comment: Have you attached your listener to any view?